# Import domain in constraints

Tags: grails, grails-domain-class

I have 2 domain classes

```
class a {
    String name
    static constraints = {
        name unique:true
    }
}

class b {
    String description
}
```

and in domain class b I want to call class a

```
import a
class b {
    String description
    static constraints = {
         description unique:'a.name'
    }
}
```

and get error

> Scope for constraint [unique] of property [description] of class [b] must be a valid property name of same class

How do I get a property from class a to b?

Comment: Description must be unique per name, or per id of A? You have a relation between A and B?

Comment: This makes no sense without a relationship between A and B.

Comment: no relationship between A and B, is possible? thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you try to do this in Grails 2+

You can't use validation that way. In your example you need to reference to a property of the same domain class. To correct the constraint in class `B` you can write:

```
class B {
    String description
    static contraints = {
        description unique:true
    }
}
```

But I think you want to import the constraints from class `a` which is done like this.

```
class B {
    String description
    static contraints = {
        importFrom A
    }
}
```

See http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/validation.html#sharingConstraints

This will import all constraints on properties that the two classes share. Which in your case is none.

---

**UPDATE**

I got a similar question and found a solution for it. So I thought to share it here with you.
The problem can be solved with a custom validator. In your case constraints for class `B`:

```
static constraints = {

    description(validator: {
        if (!it) {
            // validates to TRUE if the collection is empty
            // prevents NULL exception
            return true
        }

        def names = A.findAll()*.name
        return names == names.unique()
    })
}
```

It's difficult to answer your question correctly since the requirements are a bit odd. But maybe it will help.

Comment: yes i use grails 2.1.1, i just need validate description must unique based on class a.name, thanks

Comment: I have the same question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15371949/gorm-how-to-ensure-uniqueness-of-related-objects-property I will let you know if I find a solution

Comment: I keep coming back to the link in this post - thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You need to write a [custom validator](http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Constraints/validator.html) to check the uniqueness since it relies on more information than the single instance of `b` will have.

Something like

```
static constraints {
     description validator: { val ->
         !a.findByName(val)
     }
}
```

might do the trick.

Comment: the val is refer to description, is not working, because i need to make description unique based on name class a, example name="1" description="1" true, name="2" description="1" true, name"1" description="1" false, anyway thanks your help.